# termux-sms-send hangs

Tags: sms, permissions, termux

I installed Termux using F-Droid, and the `termux-api` package.
When I run `$termux-sms-send -n (number) text`,
the command never returns, nor does it produce errors.
I press Ctrl+C to exit.

Per the advice of the internet, I ran `strace termux-sms-send`
which led to a long bunch of output, which eventually stopped.
Unfortunately, the output isn't something I know how to interpret.

I ran `logcat`, starting the first line where I saw any reference to `termux-sms-send`:

```
execute } for name="termux-sms-send" dev="dm-69" ino=29166 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:10:32.827 14275 14275 W bash    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6030): avc: granted { execute } for name="termux-sms-send" dev="dm-69" ino=29166 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:10:32.827 14275 14275 W bash    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6031): avc: granted { execute_no_trans } for path="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/termux-sms-send" dev="dm-69" ino=29166 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:10:32.827 14275 14275 W bash    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6032): avc: granted { execute } for name="dash" dev="dm-69" ino=28367 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:10:32.831 14275 14275 W termux-sms-send: type=1400 audit(0.0:6033): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/dash" dev="dm-69" ino=28367 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:10:33.253 14278 14278 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 10309 <<<<<<
01-21 11:10:33.265 14278 14278 I AndroidRuntime: Using default boot image
01-21 11:10:33.265 14278 14278 I AndroidRuntime: Leaving lock profiling enabled
01-21 11:10:33.266 14278 14278 W libc    : Access denied finding property "odsign.verification.success"
01-21 11:10:33.271 14278 14278 W app_process: ART APEX data files are untrusted.
01-21 11:10:33.271 14278 14278 I app_process: Using CollectorTypeCC GC.
01-21 11:10:33.555 14278 14278 D app_process: Time zone APEX ICU file found: /apex/com.android.tzdata/etc/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-21 11:10:33.555 14278 14278 D app_process: I18n APEX ICU file found: /apex/com.android.i18n/etc/icu/icudt70l.dat
01-21 11:10:33.594 14278 14278 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/termux-am/am.dm': No such file or directory
01-21 11:10:33.693 14278 14278 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.termux.termuxam.Am
01-21 11:10:33.715 14278 14278 I app_process: System.exit called, status: 0
01-21 11:10:33.715 14278 14278 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
01-21 11:11:00.619 14299 14299 W bash    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6080): avc: granted { execute } for name="logcat" dev="dm-69" ino=12571 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:11:00.623 14299 14299 W bash    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6081): avc: granted { execute } for name="logcat" dev="dm-69" ino=12571 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:11:00.623 14299 14299 W bash    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6082): avc: granted { execute_no_trans } for path="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/logcat" dev="dm-69" ino=12571 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:11:00.623 14299 14299 W bash    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6083): avc: granted { execute } for name="dash" dev="dm-69" ino=28367 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
01-21 11:11:00.623 14299 14299 W logcat  : type=1400 audit(0.0:6084): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/dash" dev="dm-69" ino=28367 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.termux
```

I see some listings for "access denied", and `untrusted_app_27`,
but I don't know what to do about this.

Here is some info about my device from `termux-info`:

```
$ termux-info 
Termux Variables:
TERMUX_APK_RELEASE=F_DROID
TERMUX_APP_PACKAGE_MANAGER=apt
TERMUX_APP_PID=9970
TERMUX_IS_DEBUGGABLE_BUILD=0
TERMUX_MAIN_PACKAGE_FORMAT=debian
TERMUX_VERSION=0.118.0
TERMUX__USER_ID=0
Packages CPU architecture:
aarch64
Subscribed repositories:
# sources.list
deb https://mirror.nevacloud.com/applications/termux/termux-main stable main
# x11-repo (sources.list.d/x11.list)
deb https://mirror.nevacloud.com/applications/termux/termux-x11 x11 main
# root-repo (sources.list.d/root.list)
deb https://mirror.nevacloud.com/applications/termux/termux-root root stable
Updatable packages:
All packages up to date
termux-tools version:
1.40.5
Android version:
13
```

How, and what, do I need to do to make `termux-sms-send` a trusted application?